# Magento 2 Admin link not working

Tags: magento2, installation, admin-panel

I have installed magento 2 using composer by follow this commands:- https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-composer/

My magento set up done without any error but with this set up, my new installed magento front end is working but admin link not working.

Can anyone please help me with this? I have tried by clear cache and removed folder of var and pub/static but still same.

Sorry might be my questions will be silly, i am in learning phase so hope you guys can understand.

Thanks

Comment: can you please try to access your backend with index.php ? like www.example.com/index.php/admin

Comment: could you solve the issue?

Comment: No, i have added index.php but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I was got same issue in my window local computer and i was solved by this way.

Remove everything, except .htaccess file from pub/static folder.

Open app/etc/di.xml file and find in

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace to

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Now execute bellow commands.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub generated;

Comment: Not working above solution.

Comment: Are you using windows or ubuntu?

Comment: Mint Linux system, Thanks for your response, i will try from magento docs once again and if then also wont work, will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it again and now this time, i have not included this option in command "**--backend-frontname="admin"**".

as i have checked dev docs installation link and in that the above option not there so i removed and try again.

And its working now with auto generated admin url.